# Show only 2 rows preview of div content

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to show only two rows preview of div content?

If I use like substring in C# would cause HTML tag error issue.

so, I wonder if I could do this?

Comment: You should work on that question. Be more precise and provide some example content.

Answer (score 0):

you could do this from css to the parent element

```
overflow: hidden;
height: necessary_height_to_show_only_2_rows;
width: 100%;
display: block;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But use css would have a problem. If I have a youtube <iframe></iframe> video player in a row that would block a part of frame.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly, you have this:

```
<div>
    line-one
    line-two
    line-three
</div>
```

you can use the following css to hide the last line:

```
div {
    line-height: 14px; #for example.
    height: 28px; #double the line-height.
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

if you want to add padding/extra space - create a wrapper div.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But use css would have a problem. If I have a youtube <iframe></iframe> video player in a row that would block a part of frame.

Comment: you can check the content with js